# Wireless card for a DIY Linux router/firewall

Tags: networking, linux, wifi

I have some nice wireless [consumer](http://www.netgear.ie/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/R7000.aspx) [routers](http://www.linksys.com/us/support-product?pid=01t80000003KUz3AAG), but will soon be running into their limits in terms of bandwidth/throughput capabilities (assuming my ISP delivers on 1Gb connections). Hence, I am looking to roll my own router again for the first time since I started to use WiFi.  I also have an eye on the future (IPV6) and generally like building my own gear. I have enough parts lying around (CPU, case, RAM etc.) to provide most of the building blocks of a nice beefy router.

One thing I don't have, and have no experience with is the wireless card itself - I have never purchased one separately, only used the ones already in laptops or SFF PCs.  My larger machines have all been wired only.  My short-list of preferred features:

- Linux driver support (native preferred, not religious about it being open, just stable and performant)
- 802.11ac/n/g support
- PCI Express preferred over USB (half height option a bonus, not required)
- Decent performance (throughput) and range (anecdotal experience is fine)

Comment: Based on [the canonical Linux wireless driver list](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers), the only cards that meet your requirements are those based on the [Atheros QCA988x chip family](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath10k) and those supported by the [Broadcom bcmfmac driver](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/brcm80211#brcmfmac).  There are some Intel devices that support both AP mode and AC wireless, but I think they're laptop-only.

Comment: Many Intel adapters support both AP and AC, but most of them don't support both. That is, they only support G in AP mode. According to Emmanuel Grumbach at Intel, it's because of "This is because of regulatory matters that can't be worked around."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently decided to [build my own wireless router](https://renaudcerrato.github.io/2016/05/21/build-your-homemade-router-part1/) - and I found the [Airetos AEX-QCA9880-NX](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OJPJVV6) performing very well on my DIY machine: 3 channels 802.11ac/n/g in a miniPCIe shape.

Comment: finally got around to this, and got 2 of these (one for 2.4Ghz and one for 5Ghz) and after a little work to get the 5Ghz operating, these are working perfectly. If, like me, you will be putting these in a standard case then you will need something like this adapter: https://www.amazon.com/Sienoc-Wireless-Adapter-Antenna-linux/dp/B00GRJ5L52

Answer (score 4):

I personally have yet to find a better component for this job than the [Gigabyte GC-WB867D-I PCI-Express x1 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wi-Fi Adapter](http://www.outletpc.com/jw4213-gigabyte-bluetooth-wifi-pcie-adapter.html?utm_source=jw4213-gigabyte-bluetooth-wifi-pcie-adapter&utm_medium=shopping%2Bengine&utm_campaign=pcpartpicker&utm_content=Gigabyte%2B-%2BNetworking%20%3E%20Network%20Cards%20-%20Wireless%20%28PCI-Express%29).

- Native linux support at least in debian/ubuntu
- AC/N/G support
- PCI-E 2.0 1x (probably the single best balance between performance and compatibility of any interface type)
- Good performance reviews
- Half-height compatible
- Fully modular - antennae and chip can be refitted
- Extra bells and whistles like bluethooth

Comment: Please note that Intel cards do not support being used as AP on the 5Ghz band. [This article](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/63040bc939c2749e2215d0aa47459ca3) explains it well.