# Linux Wireless 802.11ac PCIe adapter?

Tags: linux, wireless

I've been searching for a fast internal wireless adapter for my desktop, but it seems we still have these issues with wireless networking on Linux. It should be as fast as possible and I'm not on a budget. But it absolutely has to have good drivers for Linux, preferably in kernel.

Any recommendations?

Comment: I asked a similar question here: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/420/122 - slightly different purpose (router/firewall rather than desktop). My ISP has not lived up to my expectations of 1Gb+ connections so I am holding off doing the build still, can't weigh in with personal experience